# Variable ID! remains undefined in graphql mutation

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo, react-apollo

I have mutations -

```
`export const setTimeLineOnUser = gql 
    mutation ($tID: ID!, $uID: ID! ){
        setTimeLineOnUser(userTimeLineId: $tID, timeLineUserId: $uID){
            userTimeLine {
                id
                updatedAt
                posts{
                    id
                    postType
                    updatedAt
                }
            }
            timeLineUser {
                id
                name
                email
            }
        }
    };`
```

and a function which looks like this -

```
`this.props.createTimeLine().then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.createTimeLine.id);
            this.addTimeLineToUser(response.data.createTimeLine.id, this.props.userQuery.user.id);
        });`
```

user has a one -to one relations like this -

```
`setTimeLineOnUser(userTimeLineId: ID!, timeLineUserId: ID!): SetTimeLineOnUserPayload`
```

now on running i get this error -

> Error: GraphQL error: Variable '$tID' expected value of type 'ID!' but value is undefined. Reason: Expected non-null value, found null. (line 1, column 11):
>   mutation ($tID: ID!, $uID: ID!) {
>             ^
>   GraphQL error: Variable '$uID' expected value of type 'ID!' but value is undefined. Reason: Expected non-null value, found null. (line 1, column 22):
>   mutation ($tID: ID!, $uID: ID!) {
>                        ^
>       at new ApolloError (apollo.umd.js:1959)
>       at apollo.umd.js:2670
>       at tryCallOne (core.js:37)
>       at core.js:123
>       at JSTimers.js:117
>       at Object.callTimer (JSTimersExecution.js:95)
>       at Object.callImmediatesPass (JSTimersExecution.js:199)
>       at Object.callImmediates (JSTimersExecution.js:214)
>       at MessageQueue.js:228
>       at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:218)

although `console.log(this.props.userQuery.user.id);` is returning valid ID! 
I even tried to make the mutation assigning the ids to states so that they may not be null but still no use!!! what I am doing wrong?

if you want to see the files go here - [Gist](https://gist.github.com/michaelspeed/4938f95cec41cb043b26025cfebff741)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you call the `addTimelineToUser` you give an object but you need both parameters.

```js
    componentDidMount(){

        this.props.createTimeLine().then((response) => {
            // this.addTimeLineToUser({ tID: response.data.createTimeLine.id, uID: this.props.userQuery.user.id }) wrong
            this.addTimeLineToUser(response.data.createTimeLine.id, this.props.userQuery.user.id)
        });
    }


    addTimeLineToUser = (tId, uId) => {
        this.props.setTimeLineOnUser({variables: {tId, uId}})
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
        });
    };
```

And it might be that this does not work because im not sure if the query is loaded inside the component did mount function.

Comment: console.log(this.props.userQuery.user.id); in componentDidMount actually does not return null/undefined it returns the uid. even before the function is triggered

Comment: this one actually worked! have been trying it for 3days with different combinations and this actually worked. thanks

Comment: Great! A pleasure to be of help